# Polymer dom-if not working

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, dom-if

I have this template dom-if using Polymer 1.X, and it is not working.

It is supposed to display 'Loading' when `requirement.allLoaded` is `false` and display the real content when `requirement.allLoaded` is `true`.

I switch the state of this variable in my test function. But it doesn't take effects.

```js
//Properties
requirement: {
    type:Object,
    value: {
        allLoaded: false,
        tagsLoaded: false
    }
}
//Test function
_testButton: function(){
    console.log(this.requirement);
    this.requirement.allLoaded = !this.requirement.allLoaded;
    console.log(this.requirement);

},
```

```html
<div id="modal-content">
    <template is="dom-if" if={{!requirement.allLoaded}}>
        <p>Loading</p>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if={{requirement.allLoaded}}>
        <iron-pages selected="[[selectedTab]]" attr-for-selected="name" role="main">
            <details-tab name="details"></details-tab>
            <bar-chart-tab name="barchart"></bar-chart-tab>
            <live-data-tab name="livedata" shared-info='{{sharedInfo}}'></live-data-tab>
        </iron-pages>
    </template>
</div>
```

Note: I already used this structure to display/not display things in other project (with Polymer 2) and it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only the change that does not work? I.e. it shows correctly on load?

Try notifying Polymer of the change:

`this.requirement.allLoaded = !this.requirement.allLoaded;
this.notifyPath('requirement.allLoaded');`

Comment: Well with that line it works :), thanks a lot, the subquestion is why is it working in the other project. Have a nice day thank you again

Comment: Not sure, Polymer 2.0 did many changes in the data system, but I'm not sure what caused this difference.

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#data-system

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `this.set('property.subProperty', value)` for [Observable Changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-system#observable-changes).
In your case, that's `this.set('requirement.allLoaded', !this.requirement.allLoaded);`